# Can I bulk transfer mail from a user mailbox to a shared mailbox?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

`Search-Mailbox -Identity Georgina.Williams@squared.org.uk -TargetMailbox ZZZ-georgina.williams -TargetFolder Inbox -LogLevel Full`

This line works fine. I'm just looking for a way to perform this in bulk.

Doesn't seem like there's a solution to this because it would mean I'd have to input the user mailbox names and the shared mailbox names.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please have a look at the [tour] to see how you can mark the question 'done'

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this myself, but it looks like you just need an input file with the users email address and from that perform a loop

If your input file is just a text file where email addresses are listed one on each line:

```
Get-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\EmailAddresses.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $target = 'ZZZ-{0}' -f ($_ -split '@')[0].ToLowerInvariant()
    Search-Mailbox -Identity $_ -TargetMailbox $target -TargetFolder Inbox -LogLevel Full
}
```

Or if you have a CSV file where one of the columns is named 'Email' you do

```
(Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\EmailAddresses.csv').Email | ForEach-Object {
    $target = 'ZZZ-{0}' -f ($_ -split '@')[0].ToLowerInvariant()
    Search-Mailbox -Identity $_ -TargetMailbox $target -TargetFolder Inbox -LogLevel Full
}
```